# I have problem with ckeditor in my Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I use tutorial - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/

And add `cktext_area` in _form

```
<%= f.label :body %>
<%= f.cktext_area :body %>
```

But it is not displayed

[image]

I use

`gem 'carrierwave'
 gem 'mini_magick'`

In application.js require adding, routes modified, but not working at all, and use command

`rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave`.

Help!!!

assets.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)
# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[bootswatch.scss]
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.scss, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in console?

Comment: there are no mistakes! Just show up a broken text_

Comment: You are not getting any javascript errors?  Is this app live somewhere or just local?

Comment: I run project on local machine. I am not getting any errors, the page where the editor should be rendered

Comment: What does your ```assets.rd``` look like?

Comment: Update question